# How can I mock the state during development

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm debugging on the form components based on `redux-form` lib.

However, I need to go through the requires steps every time to reach the `step N`

Is it possible to set some mock states to locate me to the `Step N` directly?

Any idea and hint?

[image: inline]

## App.tsx

```
<SearchStructureBuilderForm
    structureList={this.props.dataReducer.structureList}
    tableList={this.props.dataReducer.tableList || []}
    parentProps={this.props}
    onSubmit={this.showResults.bind(this)}>
</SearchStructureBuilderForm>
```

## SearchStructureBuilderForm.tsx

```
    render() {
        let {
            parentProps,
        } = this.props;                    

        ...
    }


    const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    const formData = state.form[FORM_NAME] || {}
    const structureList = state.dataReducer.structureList
    const email = selector(state, 'email')
    const selectedTable = selector(state, 'selectedTable')
    const structureName = selector(state, 'structureName')
    return {
        formData,
        structureList,
        email,
        selectedTable,
        structureName,
    }
    }

    export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
    )(reduxForm(formOption)(SearchStructureBuilderForm as any))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react developer tools for chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog or redux development tool